# How does code pages work in case of chinese

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, codepages

How does [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) work in case of chinese / japanese?

It is unable to encode all alphabet's characters for these languages in the limits of one byte so how does it work then?

Note that I'm taking about pre-Unicode times.

Comment: Short answer: Two bytes!!

Comment: For unicode a character can actually have TON of bytes. Especially if it has lots of modifiers. ü for intance is often 2 but can be 3 depending on normalization.

Comment: @Evert I'm talking about pre-Unicode times

Comment: In that case, you might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS

Comment: Before Unicode, it was *still* multiple bytes.  There were other [various Chinese encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding) for example..

Answer (score 0):

I'm most familiar with Japanese, but in general the strategy is the same for any language that needs more characters than fit in a single byte - you use a **variable width multibyte encoding** where some bytes are recognized as starting a "wide" character and ASCII is left alone.

In the early days so-called **"ASCII-safe"** encodings were useful. These used only **seven bits** (the high bit was always 0) so they worked with a variety of systems (including hardware) that expected only control characters to set the high bit in any byte. ISO-2022-JP is one of these and is still used in email quite often (mostly on feature phones).

Here's what ISO-2022-JP looks like if you don't decode it:

```
echo "日本語" | iconv -f utf8 -t iso2022jp | cat -v
^[$BF|K\8l^[(B
```

Note that "test" comes through unchanged and all other characters are valid ASCII; `^[` is an ASCII escape character. (ISO-2022 also has 8-bit versions, but the 7-bit is the most commonly used variety.)

Later variable width encodings, like EUC, Shift-JIS, and UTF-8 all work on the same principle except they use **binary (non-ASCII) escapes**, so the first character of any multi-byte character has the high bit set (that is, the unsigned byte value is >128). The [Wikipedia article for UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) has a nice table explaining how UTF handles this. Just like the older ASCII-safe encodings, these leave ASCII strings unmodified.

There also exist **fixed-width** multibyte encodings, but they're relatively uncommon. There was an attempt to popularize an encoding that just used two bytes for everything, called "UCS-2", but it ended up not having room for enough characters and was mostly superseded by variable width UTF-16 in the 1990s. UTF-16 is (practically speaking) the internal encoding used in Java and Javascript, but due to the history with UCS-2 sometimes things like string length work in strange ways.

Technically fixed-width [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) exists, but it's not widely used and I've never personally encountered it in the wild.

Comment: So, before UTF-n encodings there were several variable width multibyte encodings which were designed specifically for China / Japan / Korea and handle characters in the more-or-less the same way as it does in UTF-8 encodings (the leading bit indicates whether it is the part of the non-ASCII symbol or not). Am I right?

Comment: Older multibyte encodings usually had the option to be 7-bit safe, so they did **not** use the leading bit; 7-bit ISO-2022 uses the ASCII escape character (decimal value 033) for example. But basically the same idea.

Comment: Oh, ASCII escape is **octal** 033, not decimal. Wrong column :P